# Connect multiple PPG sensor to developing board

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, stm32, photodiode, light-sensor

I'm pretty new to this world, so I'm sorry if my question sounds stupid.

I want to work with multiple optical sensors to record PPG simultaneously.
In particular, I want to use the MAX86916 sensor:

https://www.analog.com/en/products/max86916.html#product-reference

and connect 6 sensors to the same board. My goal is to simultaneously record 6 different signals to work on them offline.
Does somebody know if it is possible and if I can use a standard developing board like STM32 or Arduino to do it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The 7-bit slave address (0x57) is immutable. Unless you find a controller with 6+ I2C interfaces, it won't be a straight-forward task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensor has an i2c interface with a fixed address, so you can't just connect all 6 sensors to the i2c interface of the microcontroller. However you can solve the problem with an i2c multiplexer (here's [one on a breakout board](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout/overview)). Fortunately the sensor has a FIFO so you don't have to read it immediately when it has data ready, but you will have to develop the Arduino or other microcontroller firmware yourself to select each sensor, read the data, select next, etc. Be aware your readings will not be synchronized -- the sensors don't offer a way to keep them locked together.